# "Reserved" in a data sheet

Tags: emulation

I'm trying to create a Nintendo Switch Emulator and I am connecting instructions to the operations from assembly code for the ARM57 chips that make up the Tegra X1. I have found this following data sheet:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0488c/DDI0488C_cortex_a57_mpcore_r1p0_trm.pdf

but unfortunately it is very vague and hard to understand, but I wanted to know what does the "Reserved" section mean? Has it got something to do with how it holds the registers. It can be found at page. 453. The Reserved operation is called quite often. If someone can find a better datasheet that would be great too although I must know, what is the "Reserved" Operation.

Comment: Generally speaking, this refers to bits in a register that currently don't do anything, but might in a future version of the hardware.  The programmer is being warned not to accidentally change their values when manipulating other bits in the register.  When writing an emulator, you should ignore these bits completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generally speaking, this refers to bits in a register that currently don't do anything, but might in a future version of the hardware. The programmer is being warned not to accidentally change their values when manipulating other bits in the register. When writing an emulator, you should ignore these bits completely.

by jasonharper